# django - int argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tuple'

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views, tuples

I've been looking at this for a couple hours and I can't seem to get a handle on why I'm getting this message...

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

on this line from my views.py (NOTE: Exception actually occurrs one level deeper inside django core, but this my line of code which eventually triggers the exception)...

```
service_interest = ServiceInterest.objects.get_or_create(service = service, client = client)
```

**Why am I getting this error?**  For your benefit, see below models.py, a forms.py, and a snippet from views.py.

models.py:

```
class Client(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  email = models.EmailField()
  site = models.URLField()
  contact_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today())

class Service(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ServiceInterest(models.Model):
  service = models.ForeignKey('Service')
  client = models.ForeignKey('Client')

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ("service", "client")
```

forms.py...

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):


SERVICE_CHOICES = (
    ('first_choice', 'Description of first choice'),
    ('second_choice', 'Description of second choice'),
    ('third_choice', 'Description of third choice'),
    ('other', 'Other')
  )

  SERVICE_CHOICES_DICT = dict(SERVICE_CHOICES)

  name = forms.CharField(label='What would you like us to call you?', max_length=200, required=False)
  email = forms.EmailField(label='What is your email address?', help_text='Ex: yourname@gmail.com')
  url = forms.URLField(label='If you have a website, please provide a link', required=False, help_text="Ex: www.yoursite.com")
  service_interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Please check all of the services you're interested in:", widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=SERVICE_CHOICES, required=True)
  other = forms.CharField(label='If you selected \"Other\", please specify:', max_length=200, required=False)
  message = forms.CharField(max_length=10000, required=False, label='Any other information you think we should know?', widget=forms.widgets.Textarea)

  def clean_other(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
    if 'service_interest' in cleaned_data.keys():
      options = cleaned_data['service_interest']
      if 'other' in options:
        other_input = cleaned_data['other']
        if other_input == None or len(other_input) == 0:
          raise forms.ValidationError('Required when \"Other\" is checked')

    return cleaned_data
```

relevent code from views.py:

```
  name = form.cleaned_data['name']
  email = form.cleaned_data['email']
  url = form.cleaned_data['url']
  interests = form.cleaned_data['service_interest']
  other = form.cleaned_data['other']
  message = form.cleaned_data['message']

  client = Client.objects.get_or_create(name = name, email = email, site = url)
  for interest in interests:
    service = None
    if(interest != 'other'):
      service = Service.objects.get_or_create(name = ContactForm.SERVICE_CHOICES_DICT[interest])
    else:
      service = Service.objects.get_or_create(name = other)

    # Appears to be responsible for the stack trace, even though exception
    # is one level deeper in...
    # /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
    service_interest = ServiceInterest.objects.get_or_create(service = service, client = client)
```

Comment: If I had to wager a guess, I'd say it's because a tuple is being passed to int(), and not a string or a number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple, in the form of `(instance, created)`. The second parameter tells you whether it had to create it or not, obviously enough. Do the following instead:

```
client, created = Client.objects.get_or_create(name = name, email = email, site = url)
```

Comment: Very weird. I would have thought that if you say `client = ...`, rather than `client, created = ...`, the 2nd 'return value' (of the tuple) would have been just lost. Then again, I'm a noob in Python :)

Comment: No, because the return value is a tuple, so the entire tuple is stored in the variable. The comma-delimited variable name list is a bit of magic that tells the Python parser to expand the return value (which is assumed to be something like a tuple) and store the values inside in the respective variables.